# javascript output with double quote in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

when i generate text from database using datatables in asp.net c#, i can generate this `"<a href='javascript:txtreplace('text to replace')'>" + lbltext.Text + "</a>"`

output is

`<a onclick='txtreplace('text to replace')'>text</a>`

but is in not working on webpage, it is noly working when **onclick** is in Ddouble quote like `<a onclick="txtreplace('text to replace')">text</a>`

how to generate text with double quote in **"onclick"** from database or any other solution to access javascript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to prefix your strings with @ which makes it a verbatim string, then just use " two times

```
@"<a href=""javascript:txtreplace('text to replace')"">" + lbltext.Text  + @"</a>"
```

or you escape the " with a \

```
"<a href=\"javascript:txtreplace('text to replace')\">" + lbltext.Text  + "</a>"
```

here`s some more info about verbatim and regular strings in c#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx